# wordpress blog in subdirectory or subdomain

Tags: directory, blog

I'm using Wordpress for my website.

Now I'd like to add a blog section to my website. I'd like it to be accessible like this:

http://www.mywebsite.com/blog

or even better, as a subdomain:

http://blog.mywebsite.com

I've done some research and my understanding is that the second option would be possible using a multiple-site configuration. I've tried and I broke everything :)
Otherwise I could just install a new wordpress instance but it's going to be tedious.

So the first option seems more feasible but I'm not sure how to implement it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first option (/blog/) is the easiest:

- create a new blank page called "Blog"
- navigate to "Settings > Reading" and choose this new page as the value in the "Posts Page" drop-down

Now, when you navigate to the new "Blog" page (which should be at /blog/ unless there is something unusual about your setup), all Posts are displayed, the most recent first.

Comment: I've tried that but this is for selecting the welcome page. And I already have a static home page. I can only select a value in either of the dropdowns, not both. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Settings > Reading > Front Page Displays actually is two settings.  When you select the radio button for "A static page" you then choose a front page and a posts page.  Leave your front page as-is and set posts to the blog page you created via the steps outlined by karpstrucking

Comment: actually it works, but I could not set a value in both dropdowns. This is because of the theme I use. The theme options were overriding the value in the dropdown. This is fixed now. And your suggestion works.